# Does IEEE 754 float division or subtraction by itself always result in the same value?

Tags: ieee-754

Unless an IEEE 754 is NaN, +-0.0 or +-Infinity, is dividing by itself guaranteed to result in exactly 1.0?

Similarly, is subtracting itself guaranteed to always result in +-0.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IEEE 754-2008 4.3 says:

> … Except where stated otherwise, every operation shall be performed as if it first produced an intermediate result correct to infinite precision and with unbounded range, and then rounded that result according to one of the attributes in this clause.

When an intermediate result is representable, all of the rounding attributes round it to itself; rounding changes a value only when it is not representable. Rules for subtraction and division are given in 5.4, and they do not state exceptions for the above.

Zero and one are representable per 3.3, which specify the sets of numbers representable in any format conforming to the standard. In particular, zero may be represented by a significand with all zero digits, and one may be represented with a significand starting with 1 and followed by “.000…000” and an exponent of zero. The minimum and maximums exponents of a format are defined so that they always include zero (*emin* is 1−*emax*, so zero is between them, inclusive, unless *emax* is less than 1, in which case no numbers are representable, *i.e.* the format is empty and not an actual format).

Since rounding does not change representable values and zero and one are representable, dividing a finite non-zero value by itself always produces one, and subtracting a finite value from itself always produces zero.

Comment: @user1282931: good question, and this is an excellent answer.  SEE ALSO: Online IEEE-754 Floating Point Calculator: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/

Comment: So this also holds for denormalized values?

Comment: @user1282931: The rules apply to all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing and substracting from itself, if same literal value was used - yes, IEEE754 requires to produce closest and cosistent match.

Comment: what if the value does not come from a literal but from a previous computation? or what do you mean with 'same literal value' ?

Comment: @user1282931: Some programming languages do not guarantee that, say, `x+y` always has the same value: An implementation might compute it the required precision of the format in one place but extra precision in another place. In such a situation, `(x+y) - (x+y)` could be non-zero. Also, different literal forms of the same number may be converted to different floating-point values. E.g., `4000e3` and `4e6` in C are not required to have the same value. These are programming language issues, not IEEE 7754 issues.

Comment: yeah but I mean, if the the samve variable is used. `float foo = ...; float one = foo/foo` is this guaranteed to be 1.0f?

Comment: To answer your question: Yes, `foo/foo` is guaranteed to be "1", for the reasons  Eric Postpischil  cited above.  But no,`(x+y) - (x+y)` will NOT necessarily always be "0", for every compiler.  Please read the final section of this paper:  "Lecture Notes on the Status of
IEEE Standard 754 for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic", Prof. W. Kahan: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF